# Water seeping under bottom of vinyl siding

Tags: cement, slab, leaking

Just moved in this house a couple of months ago and just noticed our home extension has water seeping through from the bottom of the vinyl siding whenever it rains. My house sits on a cement slab. I had cleared the downspout and drain extension is present, but water still coming in and it soaks my carpet. When this house was inspected, it said that the grade sloping is away from the house. I attached picture of what under the vinyl siding looked like. Please see pictures attached. Thank you!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1HhE.jpg)
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please articulate what your question is.

Comment: Poor window sealing?

Comment: Yes, please state your question. Looks like someone already knew about the problem and did a bad job trying to hide it, too.